How to rig 1/4” thick sheet metal for realistic bending animation?
How would I rig a 1/4” thick sheet metal object for animating the accurate curve bending as shown in the animated gif? Thanks for your help.

You can create this topology and align some bones with it (here the vertical bone is the root bone):

Parent With Empty Groups:

Manually assign the vertices to the correct vertex group:

Give a Copy Rotation constraint to the second small bone with the first as Target, and so on for the next ones, the Target needs to be the previous bone (you can also give them a Limit Rotation constraint if you want to make sure that they can only rotate on one axis):

Result:


Ah perfect, thank you for this breakdown! Looks like just what I need.

Hi @moonboots could you please let me know, what is the relationship if any between the first small bone pointing to the right and the large non-moving bone pointing to the left? Thanks https://i.sstatic.net/6q8eZDBM.jpg

Hi @moonboots for the image above marked with the red arrow, could you please let me know, what is the relationship if any between the first small bone pointing to the right and the large non-moving bone pointing to the left? Thanks

hello, no relations, but they are both parented to the root bone (the vertical one)

Ok thanks for letting me know

how are you getting all of the small bones to move equally when you do the bend? Thanks

Hello, as I said I gave a Copy Rotation to each bone (except the first small one), does it work?

Aaah perfect. I missed the part about Copy Rotation restraint. Yes it works perfect now. I have 6 little bones and set  the rotation limit to 15 degrees for each bone so it now goes from completely flat to a perfect 90 degree angle (15 degrees x 6) as I rotate the first little bone. Thanks again!!!
