A way to create a bend rig across specific region?
I need to rig a 1/8” thick sheet metal object to be able to animate the specific bends going from 0 to 90 degrees.
Rather than having to create intermediate subdivisions for each bend area on complicated bend shapes where each bone in the bend rig matches up with exact vertices, what would be the procedure to specify a bend region with just a start face and end face, and then have the bend rig evenly bend the region based on the number of bones in the rig? Thanks for your help. This drawing shows my current rig that works using subdivisions, but I’d like to be able to get it to work smoothly without having to make subdivisions in the object for each of those little bones.

What I’ve done so far, which probably is the tedious/beginner way:
I have a version of the object where I’ve placed 6 subdivisions for each location where a bend will take place, and it even close up the bend looks prett smooth/natural with just 6 subdivisions. Doing the manual subdivisions is fine for simpler objects like bending a sheet metal box into shape, but I realize for more my more complex shapes, subdividing and then linking all the tiny bones to these subdivided bend areas is going to take forever.

A mesh can only be bent if there are vertices either real or generated by some modifier (like Subdivision Surface for example). Bones can deform meshes, but only when there are vertices to be moved into the new deformed positions. If you do not want to create subdivisions there, you will not be able to bend it. Simple as that.

I saw some video but can’t remember what it was for exactly. The person bent a flat object following the smooth shape of a spline/curve. I’m just asking if there is something like that could apply here or if there is any other alternative non-tedious way to achieve the smooth shape you get like with subdivisions, but without manually making hundreds of subdivisions for all the different bends? Thanks for any insight.

@persyst Are you talking about bendy bones?

No need to use multiple bones. You only need two. Just create a loop where you want the centre of your bend to be then Ctrl-B to bevel and increase the number of loops to an even number. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/318101/how-to-rig-1-4-thick-sheet-metal-for-realistic-bending-animation?rq=1 And having now looked at the name of the person who asked the question, it was you!

Hi @JohnEason, could you please clarify on what your 2 bone solution is? The solution provided in the post you reference was to have all the little bones inbetween. I tried that, and it does work quick enough when doing just a few bends, but my goal in asking this question is to move to some cleaner less tedious procedure that does not need all those little bones and paired vertex groups, for working on objects needing dozens of sheet metal bends. Please let me know. Thanks

Hi @Jakemoyo, something like bendy bones using start and end, but from what I’ve see with bendy bones, you still need to make subdivisions to get a smooth bend. I’m looking for some function or way to get the smooth bend without having to manual make all the subdivisions for every bend.

Hmm... I had it working earlier this afternoon with just 2 bones but I suspect that using a third bendy bone as @Jakemoyo suggests is the way to go. However you do it you'll still need to make subdivisions to get a smooth bend.
